# How to transform a point Coordinate?

Tags: python, gdal

I want to transform lon/lat point coordinate to Albers X/Y cordinate. So I defined a function as follows:
This code modified base on section of *Coordinate conversion*  of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488765/plot-gdal-raster-using-matplotlib-basemap)

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal,osr

inprojF=r'\WGS 1984.prj'          #needed to tranform projection
outprojF=r'\WGS_1984_Albers.prj'  #wanted projection

def convertXY(x,y):  # function to convert coordinates
    xy_source=np.array([x,y])
    inprojds=open(inprojF,'r').read()
    outprojds=open(outprojF,'r').read()

    inproj=osr.SpatialReference()
    inproj.ImportFromWkt(inprojds)
    outproj=osr.SpatialReference()
    outproj.ImportFromWkt(outprojds)

    ct = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inproj, outproj)  
    xy_target = np.array(ct.TransformPoints(xy_source))
    xx = xy_target[0]
    yy = xy_target[1]
    return xx, yy
```

When I type:

```
convertXY(110.0,40.0)
```

Hint error:

```
in method 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoints', argument 1 of type    'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *'
```

Debugging the code I found that the error is in `ct.TransformPoints(xy_source)`

How to improve above code?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a problem with `TransformPoints` because it is expecting a sequence of multiple points for conversion instead of just one point.

If your aim is to call this function for every point then instead of using `TransformPoints` try using `TransformPoint` function in the following manner -

```
...
xy_target = np.array(ct.TransformPoint(x,y))
...
```

It should work.

Comment: It is still unexpectedly quitting. Hint error: `Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'.`

Answer (score 2):

[pyproj](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/) is designed exactly for that (transform coordinates between Coordinate Reference Systems)

```
from pyproj import Proj

# Adjust the proj4 string to your needs
p = Proj('+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs')

coords_albers = p(110.0, 40.0)
print coords_albers
```

Comment: THx! It is a concise and effective method.